# How can I create a list of buttons using AngularJS?

Tags: html, angularjs, web

I have some data which is presented similar to a search system (list of links on different source):

1. First unit of data ***Show Detail***
2. Second unit of data ***Show Detail***
3. ...

Each unit of data has id (*orderedNumber*) and some information which must be hidden by default. Each unit of data has button which shows this information. The button calls a function *ShowHide*. I have problem because this function doesn't work with several buttons. Information about the unit of data must be shown when I click on the button (data is determined dynamically).

html:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in results">
    {{ x.orderNumber + '. ' + x.namePackage + ' ' + x.size + ' Bytes '}} <a href={{x.link}}>Download</a> 
    <input type="button" value="Show detail" ng-click="ShowHide(x.orderNumber)" />
    <div ng-show = "IsVisible[orderedNumber]">response</div>
</div>
```

script.js:

```
    $scope.ShowHide = function (orderedNumber) {
    //This will hide the DIV by default.
    $scope.IsVisible[orderedNumber] = false;
    $scope.ShowHide = function (orderedNumber) {
        //If DIV is visible it will be hidden and vice versa.
        $scope.IsVisible[orderedNumber] = $scope.IsVisible[orderedNumber] ? false : true;
    }
};
```

How can I create a list of buttons using AngularJS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a property in the var instead of managing an array like this :

```
ng-click="ShowHide(x)"

ng-show = "x.visible"

$scope.ShowHide = function (item) {
    item.visible = !item.visible
};
```

EDIT : If you don't have any more logic in the Showhide function you also could do this :

```
ng-click="x.visible = !x.visible"
```